# Preventing QStackedWidget auto focus

Tags: qt, qt5

QStackedWidget seems to focus and select content of the first child widget when starting or switching page.

This is what I get when starting the program (the timeedit widget is focused and the first digit is selected:

[image: startup focus]

Im removing the focus by setting it to some other uneditable widget using `currentChanged` event.

Is there a better way to fix this?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 160, 351, 231))
        self.page_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.timeEdit = QtWidgets.QTimeEdit(self.page_1)
        self.timeEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 40, 118, 22))
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_1)
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        # my workaround for removing focus - set focus to the parent window on startup/page change.
        MainWindow.setFocus()
        self.stackedWidget.currentChanged.connect(self.onPageChange) 
    
    def onPageChange(self, index):
        MainWindow.setFocus()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Have a look at `QWidget`'s `setFocusPolicy()` and `setFoxusProxy()` and experiment with it. It may offer a solution to your problem.

Comment: @V.K. I checked but couldnt find a relevant solution there.

Comment: Trouble is that I do not completely understand your problem as you described it. Where would you expect the focus to be? And do you switch the pages? It seems that some code is missing.

Comment: I dont want any widget to be displayed as selected/focused when I start the program or switch page. see the updated the question and screenshot.